# How to add an external legend to ggpairs()?

Tags: r, plot, ggally

I am plotting a scatterplot matrix using `ggpairs`. I am using the following code:

```
# Load required packages
require(GGally)

# Load datasets
data(state)
df <- data.frame(state.x77,
                 State = state.name,
                 Abbrev = state.abb,
                 Region = state.region,
                 Division = state.division
) 
# Create scatterplot matrix
p <- ggpairs(df, 
             # Columns to include in the matrix
             columns = c(3,5,6,7),

             # What to include above diagonal
             # list(continuous = "points") to mirror
             # "blank" to turn off
             upper = "blank",
             legends=T,

             # What to include below diagonal
             lower = list(continuous = "points"),

             # What to include in the diagonal
             diag = list(continuous = "density"),

             # How to label inner plots
             # internal, none, show
             axisLabels = "none",

             # Other aes() parameters
             colour = "Region",
             title = "State Scatterplot Matrix"
) 

# Show the plot
print(p)
```

and I get the following plot:

[image]

Now, one can easily see that I am getting legends for every plot in the matrix. I would like to have ONLY ONE universal legend for the whole plot. How do I do that?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged `shiny`???

Comment: Removed the tag, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am working on something similar, this is the approach i would take,

1. Ensure legends are set to 'TRUE' in the `ggpairs` function call
2. Now iterate over the subplots in the plot matrix and remove the legends for each of them and just retain one of them since the densities are all plotted on the same column.

   ```
   colIdx <- c(3,5,6,7)

   for (i in 1:length(colIdx)) {

     # Address only the diagonal elements
     # Get plot out of matrix
     inner <- getPlot(p, i, i);

     # Add any ggplot2 settings you want (blank grid here)
     inner <- inner + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
       theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

     # Put it back into the matrix
     p <- putPlot(p, inner, i, i)

     for (j in 1:length(colIdx)){
       if((i==1 & j==1)){

         # Move legend right
         inner <- getPlot(p, i, j)
         inner <- inner + theme(legend.position=c(length(colIdx)-0.25,0.50)) 
         p <- putPlot(p, inner, i, j)
       }
       else{

         # Delete legend
         inner <- getPlot(p, i, j)
         inner <- inner + theme(legend.position="none")
         p <- putPlot(p, inner, i, j)
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly, achieves exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: legends is now depreceated in ggpairs, but legend = 1 works.

Answer (score 8):

Hopefully, someone will show how this can be done with `ggpairs(...)`. I'd like to see that myself. Until then, here is a solution that does not use `ggpairs(...)`, but rather plain vanilla `ggplot` with facets.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)   # for melt(...)
library(plyr)       # for .(...)
library(data.table)

xx <- with(df, data.table(id=1:nrow(df), group=Region, df[,c(3,5,6,7)]))
yy <- melt(xx,id=1:2, variable.name="H", value.name="xval")
setkey(yy,id,group)
ww <- yy[,list(V=H,yval=xval),key="id,group"]
zz <- yy[ww,allow.cartesian=T]
setkey(zz,H,V,group)
zz <- zz[,list(id, group, xval, yval, min.x=min(xval),min.y=min(yval),
               range.x=diff(range(xval)),range.y=diff(range(yval))),by="H,V"]
d  <- zz[H==V,list(x=density(xval)$x,
                   y=min.y+range.y*density(xval)$y/max(density(xval)$y)),
         by="H,V,group"]
ggplot(zz)+
  geom_point(subset= .(xtfrm(H)<xtfrm(V)), 
             aes(x=xval, y=yval, color=factor(group)), 
             size=3, alpha=0.5)+
  geom_line(subset= .(H==V), data=d, aes(x=x, y=y, color=factor(group)))+
  facet_grid(V~H, scales="free")+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Region")+
  labs(x="", y="")
```

The basic idea is to `melt(...)` your `df` into the proper format for `ggplot` (`xx`), make two copies (`yy` and `ww`) and run a cartesian join based on `id` and `group` (here, `id` is just a row number and `group` is the `Region` variable), to create `zz`. We do need to calculate and scale the densities externally (in the data table `d`). In spite of all that, it still runs faster than `ggpairs(...)`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can we get rid of the upper triangular matrix which is not contributing a lot? The reason of using ggpairs initially for me was to only display relevant information.

Comment: No.  Its not possible to set the facet themes independently.