# GGally::ggpairs - show axes and variable labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

I'm trying to create a matrix plot using `GGally::ggpairs` that just has scatterplots in the upper portion of the figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

data(iris)
ggpairs(iris, columns = 1:4, diag = "blank",
    upper = list(continuous = wrap("points", colour = "#e0f3f8", size = 1)),
    lower = list(continuous = wrap("blank"))) +
    ggplot2::theme_dark()
```

Which gives

[image: this output added].

The problem is I can't work out how to display the axis labels with the lower potion being blank. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36741664/scattermatrix-in-ggplot2-ggally-without-density-plots) explained how to remove elements but not add them back in. Other things I've tried:

`axisLabels = "show"` and `showStrips = TRUE` don't make a difference to the plot

`axisLabels = "internal"` moves the variable titles into the diagonal which I don't want. The text is also grey on a grey background, and `axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white")` didn't fix that either.

Is there a way to have variable labels above the plots and axis labels below them, while keeping the plots in the upper half of the plot?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42654928/how-to-show-only-the-lower-triangle-in-ggpairs

Comment: @RichardTelford It works with the matrix plots in the lower portion of the plot, but not if they're in the upper portion (only shows petal length/sepal width in the top right hand corner). Is there a way I can modify the `gpairs_lower` function to take that into account?

Comment: Certainly possible to modify `gpairs_lower` to make `gpairs_upper`.