# Legend using ggpairs

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, ggally

Trying to follow an example made here, I was reproducing the following code:

```
# Load required packages
require(GGally)

# Load datasets
data(state)
df <- data.frame(state.x77,
                 State = state.name,
                 Abbrev = state.abb,
                 Region = state.region,
                 Division = state.division
) 
# Create scatterplot matrix
p <- ggpairs(df, 
             # Columns to include in the matrix
             columns = c(3,5,6,7),

             # What to include above diagonal
             # list(continuous = "points") to mirror
             # "blank" to turn off
             upper = "blank",
             legends=T,

             # What to include below diagonal
             lower = list(continuous = "points"),

             # What to include in the diagonal
             diag = list(continuous = "density"),

             # How to label inner plots
             # internal, none, show
             axisLabels = "none",

             # Other aes() parameters
             colour = "Region",
             title = "State Scatterplot Matrix"
) 

# Show the plot
print(p)
```

I was supposed to get an image with legend for each plot.

But instead, I am getting one without any legend.

Any tips of why the image I am getting does not have the legends? My particular case needs them!

I am using R v. 3.2.2, and tried both in RStudio and RGui.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Presumably it came from this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945702/how-to-add-an-external-legend-to-ggpairs

Comment: And a distinct possibility is that someone decided it was a bug and fixed it.

Comment: But yes, they should be there, if you specified Legends=T, and there is no difference if you do Legends=F.

Comment: @Mike I kept Legends=T, and yes, it came from that post. I do not know what is happening. But thanks!

Comment: The question was posted in April 14, and if you look at the archives https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/GGally/ one sees that 4 new versions have come out since then. Probably they got rid of that functionality - the help says it is "not recommended" anyway.

Comment: @Mike do you know other way to insert legend in this kind of matrix using ggpairs?

Comment: I am looking at the source code now. I see that they changed the print routine and removed the legend code. It is still there, but not exported so not accessible. There may be another way to get it but haven't found it yet.

Comment: I tried get the legend from a ggplot using the function:
`g_legend<-function(a.gplot){
  tmp <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(a.gplot))
  leg <- which(sapply(tmp$grobs, function(x) x$name) == "guide-box")
  legend <- tmp$grobs[[leg]]
  return(legend)}

mylegend <- g_legend(p4)`

And then organizing in a grid.arrange from package gridExtra. But it appears that ggpairs does not works in grid.arrange function. It didnt work. 

Thanks.

Comment: Got it.... and learned something along the way.

Comment: You should post this as a seperate question. It is essentially a new one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There should be a standard way to to it, but I could not find one. The old print function is still there and accessible but as in internal function. Try this instead of the print:

```
  GGally:::print_ggpairs_old(p)
```

[image]

And if you add this (thanks to this post answer [Legend using ggpairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32927426/legend-using-ggpairs#comment53681960_32927426) )

```
colidx <- c(3,5,6,7)
for (i in 1:length(colidx)) {

  # Address only the diagonal elements
  # Get plot out of plot-matrix
  inner <- getPlot(p, i, i);

  # Add ggplot2 settings (here we remove gridlines)
  inner <- inner + theme(panel.grid = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())

  # Put it back into the plot-matrix
  p <- putPlot(p, inner, i, i)

  for (j in 1:length(colidx)){
    if((i==1 & j==1)){

      # Move the upper-left legend to the far right of the plot
      inner <- getPlot(p, i, j)
      inner <- inner + theme(legend.position=c(length(colidx)-0.25,0.50)) 
      p <- putPlot(p, inner, i, j)
    }
    else{

      # Delete the other legends
      inner <- getPlot(p, i, j)
      inner <- inner + theme(legend.position="none")
      p <- putPlot(p, inner, i, j)
    }
  }
}
```

You get something much better:

[image]

Comment: Ok, don't forget to accept the answer. And check my comment about your other question.

Comment: I edited my question adding more information. I would appreciate if you could help me! Thanks.

Comment: Post it as a new question. Otherwise it is confusing to figure out what is happening.

Comment: But I need to sleep now. Will have another look tomorrow.

Comment: `GGally:::print_ggpairs_old` seems to be no longer present in v1.4.0 of GGally. :-(