# How do I add a legend to a one column GGally::ggpairs plot?

Tags: r, ggally, ggpairs

I've created a GGally plot by group from one column of my data, however there is no legend to identify group names. How do I add a legend to the plot?

My code:

```
ggpairs(data[ ,c(2,5)],  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = group), 
        upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 3)), 
        lower = list(combo = wrap(ggally_facethist, bins = 10)), 
        diag = list(continuous = wrap("densityDiag"), 
                    mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill = group, alpha = 0.1)),
        title="Data by Group") +
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
        theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

My output:
[image]
Ideally I'd like to be able to move the legend around, if necessary, but a legend on the right side would be fine. I am also wondering whether it's possible to create a separate legend and save this to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
gg <-  ggpairs(data[ ,c(2,5)],  mapping = ggplot2::aes(color = group), 
    upper = list(continuous = wrap("cor", size = 3)), 
    lower = list(combo = wrap(ggally_facethist, bins = 10)), 
    diag = list(continuous = wrap("densityDiag"), 
                mapping = ggplot2::aes(fill = group, alpha = 0.1)),
    title="Data by Group") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 10),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

**then add**

```
gg + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

or whatever position you would like it

An external legend can be added by following directions here: [How to add an external legend to ggpairs()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22945702/how-to-add-an-external-legend-to-ggpairs)